# Why is nltk.download unable to download wordnet or any other data?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to experiment with wordnet under nltk.
None of the following commands are working in python, neither on Windows, nor on ubuntu.

```
1. nltk.download('wordnet')
2. nltk.downlaod()
```

[image: Error on ubuntu]

[image: Error on Windows]

[image: Source code of buggy file]

Comment: Please upgrade your NLTK. `pip install -U nltk`

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that.

Comment: Which version of NLTK are you using `import nltk; print(nltk.__version)`

Comment: Version is 3.2.5

Comment: Do you have internet connection? I suspect you are off-line and the index didn't get updated. Could you do `import nltk; nltk.download('popular')`?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when I was last having similar issues.

```
$ python

>>> import nltk
>>> dler = nltk.downloader.Downloader()
>>> dler._update_index()
>>> dler.download('all')
```

Comment: Alternatively, replace the last line with `dler.download('wordnet')` if it's only wordnet you require.

Answer (score 1):

After you type `nltk.download()` to get the interactive installer, type `omw` (Open Multilingual Wordnet) instead of `wordnet`.

If that doesn't work for you, you can try: `python -m nltk.downloader all` 
 (or `python -m nltk.downloader omw` ) on the command line (not the python interpreter).

Comment: For both of these cases the similar error continues. My best guess is there is some bug in the downloader code file, as the comments before the line causing error shows confusion of the coder.

Comment: The problem seems to come from out dated nltk data index. Do you have internet in your machine? The latest version of the code should automatically update the index when you do `nltk.download()`